# AutoHotKey LWin + Shift + Left/Right to Shift + Home/End

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script for AutoHotKey to map the LWin + Shift + Left/Right key combination to Shift + Home/End.

I also want to make LWin + Left/Right do Home/End, but I got this working.

Here's what I am trying right now:

```
LWin & Right::
GetKeyState, state, Shift
if state = D
    Send {Shift}{End}
Else Send {End}
Return
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, just played around with the script for a bit and got it working:

```
LWin & Left::
GetKeyState, state, Shift
If state = D
    Send +{Home}
Else Send {Home}
Return

LWin & Right::
GetKeyState, state, Shift
If state = D
    Send +{End}
Else Send {End}
Return
```

Comment: Brilliant! - struggled with the same issue. Mac people in Windowsland :-)

Comment: I feel ya. It's one of the things that makes coding on mac easier. This helped me quite a bit.

Comment: If I press first `Shift` then `Win` and right, the cursor moves to the end of line selecting the text. But if I first press `Win` and then `Shift` and right -- the text is not selected. Do you have the same issue?